# Write and read value from RFID Tag with Android BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rfid

I have an Android application that connects to a RFID Reader via Bluetooth Low Energy. But I don't exactly know how to write to the rfid tags to check if I recieve the correct value.

I'm using this RFID Reader: http://www.partitalia.biz/discoverymini
and ISO 18000-6C RFID Tags.

My current code to write to the characteristic of the tag looks like this:

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic mReadCharacteristic = mCustomService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(myCharacteristicUUID));

byte[] value = new byte[1];
value[0] = (byte) (21 & 0xFF);
mReadCharacteristic.setValue(value);
boolean status = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mReadCharacteristic);
```

But no matter if I write to the characteristic or not, the `.getValue()` method always returns the same value:

```
    final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
    if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
        for (byte byteChar : data)
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, new String(data) + "\n" + stringBuilder.toString());
    }
```

So what do I have to do to write some value to the RFID Tag and to read exactly this value?

Comment: Note that for write RFID to work, the remote device needs to have software to enable it. Nothing in the link states that capability. Have you reached out to the vendor?

Comment: Oh thanks for the hint! As far as I know it should be possible with this device, because one workmate of mine said that the vendor demonstrated writing with it. But I'll check that.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks that really seems to be the problem. May I ask you if the code in general is probably not wrong? Would be nice if I got at least the idea of reading and writing right.